# invoke the action

Tags: java, struts2

Can its possible to invoke a action automatically in Struts2. means when run the application, action can be execute without submit or clicking any event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your action directly without submitting or clicking any event you can use it directly by typing it in your adress bar.
eg;) http://ip:port/proj-name/package-namespace/ActionName

It also works if you use it with  tag. the action will be invoked if user clicks the tag.

Hope this is what you were looking for